# How to make trimStart() function available on Safari? Create if not defined

Tags: javascript, safari

I have noticed that `string.trimStart()` is [not available](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_trimstart) on Safari 11 and before.

Using it yields the error:

> trimStart is not a function

What the function does:

> The `trimStart()` method removes whitespace from the beginning of a string. trimLeft() is an alias of this method.

Is there a way to "create" this `trimStart()` function for Safari if it is not available? So calling it does not give `undefined` anymore but instead uses the self-defined prototype?

Maybe this would work:

```
String.prototype.trimStart = function() { 
    return this.replace(/^\s+/, ""); 
}
```

I wonder if this overrides the built-in `trimStart()` safely without conflict?

Comment: That caniuse page contains a link to the function's MDN page. That MDN page contains a link to a polyfill.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Is there a way to "create" this function for Safari if it is not available?

Comment: That's the whole point of a polyfill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple regex for replacing white space from the beginning of the text.

```js
if (!String.prototype.trimStart) {
  String.prototype.trimStart = function() { 
    return this.replace(/^\s+/, ""); 
  }
}

let str = '    something.  ';
const result = str.trimStart();

console.log(result) // trim the starting whitepsace;
console.log(result.length)  // get the length of the string with the white space at the end.
console.log(result + 'else') // showing the whitespace at the end of str
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with: Is there a way to "create" this trimStart() function for Safari if it is not available?

Comment: Maybe this would work: `String.prototype.trimStart = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+/, ""); }` – Now I wonder if this overrides the built-in `trimStart()` safely?

Comment: Yes, I was about to update the answer with it, but first, check if `String.prototype.trimString` exist first.

Comment: I update the answer, please check again.

Comment: Nice! So probably: `if (typeof String.prototype.trimStart !== "function") { ... } `

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the fix that even recognizes the built-in function if available.